# Multiple gmail calendars creating notifications for multiple copies of each holiday

Tags: macos, calendar

- I have 3 gmails. One for my personal email in which I make calendar events, one for one job which has calendar events for that job, and one for a second job which has calendar events for that job also.
- I use Calendar.app because it is well integrated with iOS and macOS. The issue seems to only affect macOS. (10.13.2)
- The "Holidays in United States" sub-calendar of each gmail account has been unchecked, and the events do not appear in the calendar itself.
- Today when I woke my MacBook Pro, I received 4 notifications for Christmas Day, which is tomorrow, one for each gmail account, and one for the built-in holidays calendar that Calendar.app gives you. I have since unchecked the use of the built in holidays calendar in Preferences.
- I expected to get one alert because the gmail holidays sub calendars had been unchecked, so I'd get one single alert from the built-in calendar. But instead I get all of them.
- I would like to configure this calendar app so that I only get one alert for a holiday. I would like to keep one so that it works as it is intended, so that I am informed about upcoming holidays. But I would like to not click Dismiss 3 or 4 times!